# Creating a QueryStringBindable for a nested classes in Scala and Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, nested, query-string

I'm trying to see if I can create a [QueryStringBindable](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable) for the following. 
I've a two case classes `BoundingBoxFilter` which has two `Location`s

```
case class Location(lat: Double, lon: Double) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = {
    lat == 0.0 && lon == 0.0
  }
}

case class BoundingBoxFilter(start: Location, end: Location) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = {
    start.isEmpty && end.isEmpty
  }
}
```

Now I want to define a route

```
   /filterByLocation      MyController.filter(b: BoundingBoxFilter)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what do you want the URL to actually look like?  What do you want the query string parameters to be called?  Let's say you want to call them `slat`, `slon`, `elat`, `elon`.

Something like this?

```
object BoundingBoxBindable extends QueryStringBindable[BoundingBox] {
  def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]) = {
    for {
      slat <- params.get("slat")
      slon <- params.get("slon")
      elat <- params.get("elat")
      elon <- params.get("elon")
    } yield {
      try {
        Right(BoundingBox(Location(slat.toDouble, slon.toDouble), Location(elat.toDouble, elon.toDouble)))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => Left(e.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }
  def unbind(key: String, v: BoundingBox) = {
    s"slat=${v.start.lat}&slon=${v.start.lon}&elat=${v.end.lat}&elon=${v.end.lon}"
  }
}
```

[There is good example on the PlayFramework API Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.QueryStringBindable)